# When dividing by a fraction, why can you not take the reciprocal of term involving addition/subtraction?

Tags: fractions

Given something like:

$$\frac{a}{\frac{a}{b}}$$
You would multiply the numerator $a$ by the reciprocal of the denominator, $\tfrac ba$  to get:
$$
a\cdot\frac{b}{a}= \frac{ab}{a}=b
$$
Given
$$
\frac{1}{\frac 1a + \frac 1b}
$$
By taking the LCM and adding the denominators you get:
$$
\frac{1}{\left(\frac{a+b}{ab}\right)}
$$
Given the reciprocal division rule in example one:
$$
\frac{ab}{a+b}
$$

Why can you not take the reciprocal of $\frac 1a + \frac 1b$ to begin with? I did this and ended up with:
$$
1\cdot\left(\frac a1 + \frac b1\right)
=a + b 
$$

However $\frac{1}{1/a + 1/b}$ is not the same as $a+b$ so this is incorrect. I was trying to find a similar example online but I could not, why is this incorrect? Does the rule only work with one fraction as the denominator and not terms linked by addition and/or subtraction?

Comment: This is *exactly* the reason you should be using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)!

Comment: Sorry! I am reading the page now!

Comment: Cool!  I did the first edit for you ...

Comment: Thanks, I am working on the rest!

Comment: Your edit made the result of the first multiplication $a$ instead of $b$.

Comment: Welp! Thanks Ross, I'm struggling over here...

Comment: @Sphygmomanometer Very nice typesetting! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you took the reciprocal of $\frac 1a+\frac 1b$ to get $a+b$, you implicitly assumed that the reciprocal of a sum is the sum of the reciprocals. This is not true.

Note that $\frac 1a$ is $a^{-1}$. Just as the square of a sum is not the sum of the squares (in general), that is, $(x+y)^2\neq x^2+y^2$, so also the reciprocal of a sum is not in general the sum of the reciprocals: $(x+y)^{-1}\neq x^{-1}+y^{-1}$.

Comment: Nope, not me. My name is pretty common.

Answer (score 0):

The reciprocal of $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}$, is by definition 
$$
\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}} = \frac{1}{\frac{a+b}{ab}} = \frac{ab}{a+b}.
$$

So your reasoning fails because $\frac{a}{1} + \frac{b}{1}$ is not the reciprocal of $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}$.